# how to make a Batch file that runs all my listed commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I have made a batch file to run one command on my database. when I click on it, its working fine.

Command-

```
start db2cmd.exe "db2 connect to QATEST"
```

screenshot of successful completion

[successful completion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZHC7.jpg)

But after adding one another command in my batch file it is giving me error.

I want to run this command `"db2 select * from db2admin.table_a"` on my opened command line, in mentioned first screenshot.

I used below command for this-

```
start db2cmd.exe "db2 connect to QATEST" "db2 select * from db2admin.table_a"
```

screenshot of error occured

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvBFr.jpg)

but it doesnot work somehow. and at the end of successful completion of command the opened cmd should close.

How to do it? can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Govind,

It appears that your program or the cmd window is separating your input. I would suggest adding " " around the entirety of our input. IF the DB2cmd.exe can (after opening the program) can accept the input string you listed above: "db2 connect to QATEST" "db2 select * from db2admin.table_a" then the " " are the solution.

Comment: `start db2cmd.exe "db2 connect to QATEST" "db2 select * from db2admin.table_a" ""` do you mean like this ???

Comment: Forgive me, try this:   start db2cmd.exe ""db2 connect to QATEST" "db2 select * from db2admin.table_a""    The point being to encapsulate all of the parameters you are attempting to pass to the program.

Comment: I do not have the program that you are referencing so I can not test that. I do now that if you use the start command and then specify parameters with quotes whatever is inside that first set of quotes will be sent to the program.

Comment: yes i know that.. and its working fine as first screeshot.. but i want to run two parameters one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a /wait in your first START, so the second one does not execute until the first has ended.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no particular reason that you need this to open in a new CMD window, then the `start` is unnecessary.  Simply change your batch file line to this:

```
db2cmd.exe "db2 connect to QATEST" "db2 select * from db2admin.table_a"
```